# Right way to handle activites and neccessary classes

Tags: android, class, android-activity

My goal is to practice programming and the logic behind the classes and the activities in android trough writing an application.

My app is already 1/3 done but I don't know the right way to move on.

Here's what the app does: 
It will help people to practice the rules of a certain sport with 3 phases of questions. 
First Phase: True-False Questions
Second Phase: 1 Question with 3 possible answers
Third Phase: Images where the user should mark the answers on the pictures

I've already created a Questions class, which makes me able to generate Question Objects and there's already a Phase One Activity, which handles the questioning correctly.

However, I read that I should not swap a layout in one activity which requires me to create a new activity, because the first the true-false layout and the 3 answer option layout would be different.

Where should I put my methods which I used in the first phase and it could be used in the second one as well (random number generator, answer checker, etc.) to avoid double coding?

Comment: TLDR; can you please edit your answer and be more objective? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: you dont need to create a new activity for every phase. Just work with fragments and youre done